# Is it possible to generate preview/sample chapters directly

Tags: xetex, pdftex, printing, preview, publishing

If I have a commercial book of 10 chapters. Is it possible to generate free preview/sample material of different chapters: lets say the sample material will include (/frontmatter + chapter1, chapter3, chapter10 + /backmatter). I am using memoir.

Requirements: 
1. Maintain page numbering
2. Keep the TOC intact

The only way I found is to do it manually as follows:
1. Compile full version
2. Extract TOC and the desired chapters using [pdftk in.pdf cat out.pdf]
3. concatenate the different pdf files.

However, is there away to do this directly in latex, xetex, etc.?

I provided sample material as my MWE if anyone have a solution.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
{\mbox{}\vfill  \HUGE \bfseries A Very Interesting Book \vfill \mbox{}}
\newpage
\chapter{Preface}
\lipsum
\newpage
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{One}
This is a sample preview chapter.
\chapter{Two}
\lipsum
\chapter{Three}
This is a sample preview chapter.
\chapter{Four}
\lipsum
\chapter{Five}
\lipsum
\chapter{Six}
\lipsum
\chapter{Seven}
\lipsum
\chapter{Eight}
\lipsum
\chapter{Nine}
\lipsum
\chapter{Ten}
 This is a sample preview chapter.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can help yourself with use `includeonly` macro:

```
\includeonly{
%    One,
%    Two,
    Three,  % tha case when you like to compile only this chapter
%    Four,
%    Five,
%    Six,
%    Seven,
%    Eight,
%    Nine,
%    Ten
            }
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \documentclass{memoir}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \frontmatter
\tableofcontents                                 
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \mainmatter
    \include{One}
    \include{Two}
    \include{Three}
    \include{Four}
    \include{Five}
    \include{Six}
    \include{Seven}
    \include{Eight}
    \include{Nine}
    \include{Ten}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \backmatter
\include{bibliogrphy}     % literatura
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\end{document}
```

Comment: This will maintain page numbering?

Comment: this will maintain all, `tableofcontents`, page numbering, chapter, section ... figures, tables equation numbering :-). just make short test with your real document.